# Why does `react-native run-ios` show "No bundle URL present" until I reset it?

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, device-emulation

With my React Native app, when I run `react-native run-ios`, it shows this screen:

[image]

When I press `cmd-R` to reload, it goes away. This happens most, but not all of the time. It's not just with a particular project; when I create a new project from scratch, it's the same.

I'm sure this could happen for a variety of reasons, and I'd need to give more info to narrow it down, but does anyone know how I could approach figuring out why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because your simulator opening the app faster than metro bundler server. In my case, it's often happened when I stop the metro bundler server and still have simulator running my applications and there is a warning message that saying metro bundler is not connected. Either way, as long as reloading the app still working, that means there is nothing wrong with your react-native configuration.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to avoid it?

Comment: ...other than reloading every time?
If not, do you think this is worth flagging as a bug?